# Is there any Acknowledgment Instruction?

Tags: environments

I'm working on a paper and I want to know if there is any instruction to generate Acknowledgment section. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Some document classes provide a command/environment for acknowledgments, if they want a particular typesetting for them; usually they're classes specific for a journal or a conference. In a thesis it may be an unnumbered chapter in the backmatter or frontmatter, a final section in the introduction or whatnot. In a paper, a final section or a couple of paragraphs at the end of the introduction could do.

Comment: This depends on several things. You should at least mention the `documentclass` you're using for your paper.

Comment: As already mentioned, this depends on the document class being used.  The AMS classes do *not* include a dedicated acknowledgments environment; this is conventionally handled by `\section*`.